# Border around content Skeleton framework

Tags: css, html, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm having the hardest time figuring out what's going on here: http://traviskoenig.brentthelendesign.com/html/. There's a weird border around the body content, the footer, and a 28px margin on the top of the page. I'm not sure what's going on here, but Firebug shows me this code:

`html {
    margin-top: 28px !important;
}`

Does anyone have any thoughts on these wierd gaps? Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize if there is something else similar to this question out there.

Comment: There is a margin given for `#content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're letting a margin of 10 pixels to the right and left at the next class:

```
.column, .columns {
   float: left;
   display: inline;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Try to remove to:

```
.column, .columns {
   float: left;
   display: inline;

}
```